# C# - datagridview add new line to cell when user type and the text (value) reaching the margin

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have set the default cell style to warpmode=true and the autosizerowsmode=true but still when i am typing this is the result:

http://www.siz.co.il/my/knzmjjzy4hm1.png

**But my goal is: (Automatic when user typing)**

http://www.siz.co.il/my/ohkm2yngyzzn.png

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting `UpdateSourceTrigger` to `PropertyChanged`?

For example:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="" Binding="{Binding Text, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```